# Restricting an NHibernate query using ICriteria according to an enumeration of enums

Tags: nhibernate, enums, criteria-api

I have an entity, with a field of type enum, that is persisted as an integer in my database.

When retrieving objects from the database using ICriteria, I wish to restrict the results to those with the field being a member of a collection of enum values. Does Restrictions.In work with a collection of enums?

The following does not work. Do I have to perform something like type-casting at the "restrictions.in" part of the query?

```
var myEnumCollection = new MyEnum[] { MyEnum.One };
return FindAll<MyType>(Restrictions.In("EnumProperty", myEnumCollection));
```

FindAll is a method encapsulating

```
criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(Session).List<MyType>()
```

Comment: A few things may help get you an answer here...1) Post the mapping for your enum property, 2) Post the resulting sql that is generated by this critiera query.

Comment: I am having the same problem as yours ( I have converted my enum to int and still I am getting an error that says "Cannot use collections with InExpression" . Since It has been a very old question I wonder if you have found a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess would be that you'll need to compare against the integer values of the enum members (assuming that you're mapping the enum as an integer); so something like:

```
var myEnumCollection = new int[] { MyEnum.One }; 
return FindAll<MyType>(Restrictions.In("EnumProperty", myEnumCollection));
```

May be the solution that you're after. If you update your post with further details (mapping of the enum member and the sql being generated by the query), I may be able to provide further assistance.